# how can a login user take part in seminar

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I work on a project.The pariticipants want to join a seminar.From admin site i could manage that.

Relation between seminars and participants

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :seminars
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable
end
```

As we see  i used devise for email sending and it is working as well. Now i want that the participants should be able to take part in a seminar.
Can anyone please me how to do this. I searched alot about this issue ,couldn't find.I am newbie on rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as your information above participants and seminars has many to many relationship, you can add field as information below

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  # -> participant_seminars -> seminars
  has_many :participant_seminars, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant_seminars,   :allow_destroy => :true  
  has_many :seminars, through: :participant_seminars
end

class Seminar < ActiveRecord::Base
  # -> participant_seminars -> participants
  has_many :participant_seminars, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :participant_seminars,   :allow_destroy => :true  
  has_many :participants, through: :participant_seminars
end

class ParticipantSeminar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :participant
  belongs_to :seminar
end

# your schema probably look like this

create_table "participant_seminars", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "participant_id"
  t.integer  "seminar_id"
  t.string   "user_part"
end
```

you can use table in ParticipantSeminar and add field in this table 
for example user_part as string, so each participant connect through seminar with user_part...

#### edit 2

for current_participants for one of seminar

in seminar model (seminar.rb)

```
def current_participants
  self.participants
end
```

this will give you all participant member of one seminar (see sample below in controller

```
@seminar = Seminar.first
@participants = @seminar.current_participants
```

Comment: i created this table ParticipantSeminar. But now devise provide me the method current_participant. So if i want to add this current_participant to one of  seminars.How could i do that. Can you give an example as well please